# Block to the right with text align to the left (no float, one div only)

Tags: html, css

I want a container block with the same width as that of its longer child. The block most be posionated to the right with its content align to the left (as in the image). Is there a way to accomplish this with no float property and using only one div?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elegant way:

`div {display: table; margin-left: auto; text-align: left;}`

Answer (score 1):

try this and check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ct2syhp/4/)

```
.box {
      width: 40%;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on what you are asking for, but here is a JSFiddle using p elements inside of one div.
https://jsfiddle.net/3ct2syhp/

CSS

```
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
<p>
I want a container block with the same width as that of its longer child. The block most be posionated to the right with its content align to the left (as in the image). Is there a way to accomplish this with no float property and using only one div?
</p>
<p class="box">
I want a container block with the same width as that of its longer child. The block most be posionated to the right with its content align to the left (as in the image). Is there a way to accomplish this with no float property and using only one div?
</p>
<p>
I want a container block with the same width as that of its longer child. The block most be posionated to the right with its content align to the left (as in the image). Is there a way to accomplish this with no float property and using only one div?
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly you don’t understand, so I can make it clearer?